# REF CURSOR get a column from a procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g

I have a procedure I am running from SQL developer. It pumps out about 50 columns. Currently I am working on a bug which is updating one of these columns. It is possible to just show column X from the result?

I am running it as

```
 VARIABLE cursorout REFCURSOR;
 EXEC MY_PROC('-1', '-1', '-1', 225835, :cursorout);
 PRINT cursorout;
```

Ideally I want to print out the 20th column so would like to do something like

```
 PRINT cursorout[20];
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the DBMS_SQL package.  You can take a cursor and get it's metadata (#columns, etc), then extract specific column values by index.  You would probably need to put that in some sort of function for sqlplus to call.  Other than that, I don't know of a way to have the PRINT command only print a specific column from a refcursor.

Comment: I know the column names and the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is possible to just show column X from the result?

Not without additional coding, no.

As @OldProgrammer said in the comment to your question you can use `dbms_sql` package to describe columns and pick one you like.

But, if, as you said, you know column names, the probably easiest way to display contents of that column would be using XML functions, `xmlsequence()` and `extract()` in particular.

Unfortunately we cannot pass SQL*PLUS bind variable as a parameter to the `xmlsequence()` function, so you might consider to wrap your procedure in a function, which returns refcursor:

Test table:

```
create table t1(col, col2) as
  select level
       , level
    from dual
   connect by level <= 5;

SQL> select * from t1;

       COL       COL2
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          2
         3          3
         4          4
         5          5
```

Here is a simple procedure, which opens a refcursor for us:

```
create or replace procedure p1(
   p_cursor out sys_refcursor
) is
begin
  open p_cursor for
     select * from t1;
end;
/
Procedure created
```

Here is the function-wrapper for the `p1` procedure, which simply executes the procedure and returns refcursor:

```
create or replace function p1_wrapper
return sys_refcursor is
  l_res sys_refcursor;
begin
  p1(l_res);
  return l_res;
end;
/
Function created
```

The query. Extract path is `ROW/COL2/text()`, where `COL2` is the name of a column we want to *print*.

```
select t.extract('ROW/COL2/text()').getstringval() as res
  from table(xmlsequence(p1_wrapper)) t ;
```

Result:

```
RES                                                                             
--------
1                                                                               
2                                                                               
3                                                                               
4                                                                               
5                                                                               

5 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion，you can define a cursor in procedure MY_PROC,and put which column is updated in the cursor(for example 20) and then return then cursor.Or you just create a table to record every execute result of your procedure.